# UITableView sticking in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` in an app that you can use your finger to scroll up and down. Users who have updated to `iOS8` who tell me it is now sticking and it does not scroll up or down. It appears to be random. Sometimes it works, other times it does not. By moving to a different view and returning sometimes unlocks it.

The `UITableView` is populated with an array of `UIButtons` (one example shown below). It works perfectly in iOS7. Is there something that has changed min iOS8 that I am unaware of?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell ==nil)
{
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

/* this is man example of a button being established. 5 buttons are actually made*/

```
UIButton* button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,160, 160)];
[button1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Button1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button1 setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:19/255.0f green:73/255.0f blue:17/255.0f alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button1.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:24];
button1.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
button1.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(action1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button1 setTitle:@"Menu" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

/* the buttons are stored into an array*/

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:button1];
/*other buttons added to the array*/


[cell addSubview:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

return cell;
```

Comment: You are using different `initWithStyle:` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, why not always use `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`? Personally I would use Storyboards and a custom cell subclass. This way the cell is always guaranteed to be non-nil and you do not need to worry about adding subviews multiple times during re-use (causing errors) or not adding the subviews to the `contentView`. As an aside, Apple now recommend using Dynamic Type rather than setting the font size directly so that the size of text is now under the user's control.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible things:

- Better to use cell.contentView to add subviews
- You always add subviews to the existing cells without removing the previous added

Answer (score 0):

`UIButton`s in scroll views can cause issues with scrolling.

Try `tableView.canCancelContentTouches = YES;`

If that doesn't help try to additionally subclass `UITableView`, overwrite `touchesShouldCancelInContentView:` and return `YES` there.

Comment: Thanks - where would I put this line?

Comment: Either in `viewDidLoad` or wherever you set up / configure your table view.

Comment: It didn't make any difference I am afraid.

Comment: Simple test: Does scrolling work if you do **not** add the buttons to the cell?

Answer (score 0):

Try using TapGesture instead of button.
I met the same problem and finally TapGesture solved the problem.

In iOS8,when you put a button on a cell,if the button is not big enough and you try to scroll the tableView while your finger is within the area of the button,the tableView will simply not scroll.
PS: You can try make the button smaller,and drag outside of the button,you will find it scrolls just as you wish.